# Missing values, merging in R

Tags: r, list, transform

I have 2 lists (of different length). Columns of first - date, amount; columns of second - date, amount. I need to combine this two lists, so for a coresponding date amount of the first is replaced with the volume of a second. List1 one contains all the needed dates, list2 - doesn't. That's why I need amount levels for corresponding dates of list2 and if the date is missing - of the list 1.

In my opinion, something like inner_join with the key of date should help, but i don't know how to do it using r code.

e.g.

```
List 1:
Date - Amount 
1/09 - 0
2/09 - 0
3/09 - 0
4/09 - 0

List 2:
Date - Amount 
1/09 - 300
3/09 - 50
```

Combined (what I need :)):

```
Date - Amount 
1/09 - 300
2/09 - 0
3/09 - 50
4/09 - 0
```

Can somebody help? 
I've tried `inner_join(l1, l2)`, but the result is empty. (Might be because I compare dates???)

Comment: Could you please include your code.  No-one can fix your problem because all we know is that there are two tables.  You need to give us something to work with.

Comment: I don't have it. I tried the merge and join methods, but it didn't work. Count it as a problem solving task

Comment: Well **say so**!  How do we know what you tried (not many of us are telepathic)?  Edit your question to include what you tried, your merge and join methods for a start.  Also maybe a short example of your table.  It may just be a simple typo (we've all made them).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming df1 and df2 are the same length and there is a 1-1 correspondence of unique dates (or some other way to uniquely match rows) sort the data frames and then assign the column of df2 to df1:

```
df1[order(df1$date,)]
df2[order(df2$date,)]
df1$amount <- df2$amount
```

If you don't want to overwrite df1$amount:

```
df1$new_amount = df2$amount
```

If you are not able to simply order the data frames by date, then take a look at the packages dplyr or data.table to see how to do efficient joins:

[dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)

[data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)